# URLImage.createToStorage failing in codenameone

Tags: java, image, codenameone

I'm trying to create a URL image from a imgur png with codenameone, using this code:

```
Form hi = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getWidth() / 5, 0xffff0000), true);
URLImage background = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "test2.png","https://i.imgur.com/VMwUrqH.png", URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
background.fetch();
hi.add(background);
hi.show();
```

But it just gives me this error:

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - create image failed for the given image data of length: 7165
```

Comment: `fetch()` is not  necessary. Try deleting `test2.png` from the `.cn1` directory then re-run the app with network monitor running. What's the output in the network monitor.

Comment: It comes back with 2 GETs., the first to https://i.imgur.com/VMwUrqH.png responds with 302. The second to https://m.imgur.com/VMwUrqH?r responds with 200, length of 7165, response time 132 ms, download time 45 ms. So that all seems ok?

I'm wondering if the problem is with viewing the image. I was able to download it with Util.downloadUrlToStorage, but when I try to open it with ImageViewer I get the same error

Comment: On second thought, when trying to open the downloaded file in .cn1 with paint.net, it says error opening the image and it's only 3 kb, when it should be larger. So neither way downloaded the image properly

Comment: It is an issue of user-agent. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given file is a valid PNG image data, 512 x 566, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced. It should work fine with Codename One, but it's not so. Your code gives me your same exception.

Indeed, the file downloaded by Codename One is completely different from the file that we can download from a browser. Codename One downloads a file that is a (valid?) PNG image data, 1080 x 216, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced. I suspect the server is applying a redirect to avoid automatic downloads like this one.

To confirm my hypothesis, I changed the user-agent of Codename One, assigning it the same one of my browser:

```
ConnectionRequest.setDefaultUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0");
```

The result is that it works! :-)

However, to force Codename One to re-download the file with the given user-agent, you must delete the `test2.png` file from the `.cn1` directory.

This is the full working code:

```
Form hi = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ConnectionRequest.setDefaultUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0");
        EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getWidth() / 5, 0xffff0000), true);
        URLImage background = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "test2.png", "https://i.imgur.com/VMwUrqH.png", URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
        background.fetch();
        hi.add(background);
        hi.show();
```